# setUndecorated(true) content of the JFrame not displaying

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a gui with java swing who is supposed to be implemented on an LCD touch screen. The gui will take all the screen and is not supposed to be closable. So "setUndecorated(true)" is essential.
Problem, when I'm using it, all the content of the frame is not displaying, only the buttons appears when I'm moving my mouse over them. Then all the content appears when I maximise and minimise the frame.
Here is the code I'm using :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Création de notre JFrame
    fenetre = new JFrame();
    fenetre.setTitle("IHM");
    fenetre.setSize(800, 600);
    fenetre.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    fenetre.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    support = new JPanel();

///////Adding content to the JPanel()/////////////

    fenetre.setContentPane(support);
    fenetre.setUndecorated(true);
    fenetre.setVisible(true);

}
```

The only solution I've find so far is to change the size of the frame after set the frame visible like so :

```
fenetre.setSize(801, 601);
fenetre.setSize(800, 600);
```

But I'm not really correcting the problem, just getting around it.

(EDIT)
My appologies for that uncomplete code.
Here is a complete exemple that you can test yourself.
First test it with undecorated to false, then try with undecorated to true and visualise the content of the window by maximising and minimising the gui.
Finally, try it with the Quick fix in the bottom of the code.

the code :

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class test {

    //Declarations
    private static JFrame fenetre;
    private static JPanel support;
    private static JLabel l1, l2;
    private static JComboBox<String> c1, c2;
    private static JButton b1, b2;

    //List to initiate the comboBoxes
    private static String[] listC1 = {"Peter", "Alex", "Jhon", "Bran"};
    private static String[] listC2 = {"10", "20", "32", "45"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Initialisation of the JFrame
        fenetre = new JFrame();
        fenetre.setTitle("IHM");
        fenetre.setSize(800, 600);
        fenetre.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fenetre.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //Initialisation of the JPanel
        support = new JPanel();
        support.setBackground(Color.red);
        support.setPreferredSize(fenetre.getSize());

        //Initialisation of the components
        l1 = new JLabel("What's my name");
        l2 = new JLabel("What's my age");
        c1 = new JComboBox<String>(listC1);
        c2 = new JComboBox<String>(listC2);
        b1 = new JButton("validate name");
        b2 = new JButton("validate age");

        //Creating layout
        support.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        //Adding components
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 0, 0);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        support.add(l1, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        support.add(c1, gbc);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 20, 0);
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        support.add(b1, gbc);

        gbc.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 0, 20);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        support.add(l2, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        support.add(c2, gbc);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20);
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        support.add(b2, gbc);

        //Adding Listeners
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("My name is " + c1.getSelectedItem());
            }
        });

        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("My age is " + c2.getSelectedItem());
            }
        });

        //Adding the JPanel to the content pane of the JFrame
        fenetre.setContentPane(support);

        //Setting undecorated true (switch between true and false for testing)
        fenetre.setUndecorated(false);
        fenetre.setVisible(true);

        //Quick fix, uncomment to test
        //fenetre.setSize(801, 601);
        //fenetre.setSize(800, 600);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not add any buttons.

Comment: As achAmháin mentioned, you need to use a LayoutManager properly.  The fact that you’re calling `setSize(800, 600)` instead of `pack()` suggests you are not.

Comment: `I'm not allowed to show the content of the code` - of course you can!!! We don't care about your real application, only code that demonstrates the problem you are describing. You question is about the visibility of buttons. So just create dummy button with any text and no processing logic. That is post a proper [mcve].

Comment: I Edited the post to show you an exemple

Comment: `I Edited the post to show you an exemple` - that is NOT an [mcve]. Again your question was about buttons not showing. Are the labels and combo boxes relevant to the stated problem? Is the ActionListener code relevant to the stated problem. Also, why do you have all the GridBagLayout code? Is the GridBagLayout relevant to the problem? You could just use a FlowLayout and there will be far less code. The point of the "MCVE" is to simplify the code as much as possible so we can see at a glance exactly what you are doing. Also class names should start with an upper case character.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your code. It works fine for me. That is I see 6 components in the center of the frame, whether the frame is decorated or not. `...implemented on an LCD touch screen` Maybe this is a version platform issue. I use JDK 8 on Windows 7.

Comment: weird.As I mentionned before, my problem in not that buttons are not showing, the problem is that all the content is not showing. I've only mentionned buttons because they are poping when I mouse over them (probably because the mouseOver function updating them). For the JDK I'm using, according to the java -version command, it's openJDK 1.8.0_121 and i'm using a linux OS. the application is meant to be on touch screen, but for now I'm testing it with my LCD PC monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You don't add any buttons to your `JPanel` so how do you expect it to display them?

Either way, here's a simple example of displaying a button:

```
JFrame fenetre = new JFrame();
fenetre.setTitle("IHM");
fenetre.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
fenetre.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
fenetre.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

JPanel support = new JPanel();
JButton button = new JButton("button");
support.add(button);
fenetre.setContentPane(support);
fenetre.setVisible(true);
```

Note that you should use a proper [layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

I also added [`setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState(int)) to fill the screen, and [`setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)) as you didn't want the screen to be closable.

Comment: I'm not allowed to share the code of this application. The part where you have //Adding content to the JPanel()// is where I add the content of the pannel. I Have a JFrame with a card layout to switch between my JPannels. My JPannel are mainly using GridBadLayouts. As I mentionned before, it's only when I use setundecorated(true) that my content is not dispaying

Answer (score 0):

> Problem, when I'm using it, all the content of the frame is not displaying, only the buttons appears when I'm moving my mouse over them.

Components should be added to the panel/frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.

If you add components to a visible frame, then the basic logic is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate(); // to invoke the layout manager
panel.repaint(); // make sure panel is repainted
```

Comment: Components are added before the frame is made visble. This is done in the //Adding content to the JPanel()// part. As I mentionned to achAmháin, I'm not allowed to show the content of the code that is working well. It's only when I use setUndecorated(true) that the content is not displayed.

Comment: @ichigovingt-neuf, Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test the code you post to verify your stated problem.